# Play error on startup: No implementation for play.api.db.Database was bound

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

When I attempt to run the Play application (Play 2.5.4) I get the following error:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.db.Database was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.Database
    for parameter 0 at ds.qb.manage.ManageQueryBuilder.<init>(ManageQueryBuilder.scala:30)
  while locating ds.qb.manage.ManageQueryBuilder
    for parameter 16 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:107)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
```

This is my database setup, any ideas? I have the definition twice because I access the database both through Slick and JDBC.

```
play.db {
  # The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  config = "db"
  default = "default"

  # Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
  # settings by changing the prototype:
  #prototype {
    # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
    #hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
    #hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
  #}
}

  db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2"
  db.default.username=root
  db.default.password=xxxxx


db2 = {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2"
  driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
  user=root
  password=xxxxxx
}
```

**UPDATE**

The build.sbt file:

```
name := """myapp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
libraryDependencies += "org.pivot4j" % "pivot4j-core" % "0.9" 
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.0" 

// properties file
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0" 

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.14"

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

// mondrian
resolvers += "Pentaho Releases" at "http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/"
```

Comment: Did you include the JDBC dependency in your `build.sbt`?

Comment: Yes: `libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"`

Comment: That's the MySQL driver. You also need the `jdbc` dependency (shortcut for `"com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc" % "2.5.4"`), see [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase#Configuring-JDBC-connection-pools).

Comment: This is what I have: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)
`

Comment: added the complete build.sbt to the question

Comment: Did you get it? I'm having this problem now.

Comment: I am also having this problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case application.conf didn't have proper db parameters

example

```
  db.default.driver = org.h2.Driver
  db.default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"
  db.default.username = sa
  db.default.password = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application.conf should look like below:

```
db.dev_mysql {
  driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" 
  # JDBC connection string. "useAffectedRows" must be set to true.
  url = "jdbc:mysql://dev01:3306/dev_db?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&connectionCollation=utf8_unicode_ci&useSSL=false&useAffectedRows=true"

  url = ${?DATABASE_URL}
  hikaricp {
    # Whether autocommit should be used
    autoCommit = true
    # The connection timeout
    connectionTimeout = 10 seconds
    # The idle timeout
    idleTimeout = 5 minutes
    # The max lifetime of a connection
    maxLifetime = 10 minutes
    # If non null, the query that should be used to test connections
    connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
    # Minimum number of idle connections maintained in the pool.
    minimumIdle = 10
    # The maximum number of connections to make.
    maximumPoolSize = 20
    # If non null, sets the name of the connection pool. Primarily used for stats reporting.
    poolName = "mysql"
    # A SQL statement that will be executed after every new connection creation before adding it to the pool
    connectionInitSql = "SELECT 1"
    # If non null, sets the transaction isolation level
    transactionIsolation = TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    # The validation timeout to use
    validationTimeout = 5 seconds
  }
}
```

When Play starts, it creates a database connection-pool with the name of `dev_mysql` by loading the params from db.`dev_mysql` json in application.conf

How to execute queries :

We can use a [NamedDatabase](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/java/play/db/NamedDatabase.html) annotation.

```
class CustomController @Inject() (
                                             val config: Configuration,
                                             @play.db.NamedDatabase("dev_mysql") db : Database,
                                             controllerComponents: ControllerComponents,
                                           ) extends ApiController(controllerComponents)  {
    def createReportDefinition = Action { implicit ctx ⇒

      val conn = db.getConnection(false)
      val sqlQuery = "select 1"
      val prepStmt: PreparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery)
      prepStmt.execute()
      conn.commit()
      conn.close()
      Ok
      }
```